# How TCP port numbers been choose?

Tags: tcp, udp, port

When am working with TCP, how do I know that this port number will be the end point of my server that am requesting to? 
For example , I send a request to my server that I need an image. What will be the destination port number in this case?

Comment: Are you asking on an architectural basis, or are you using a specific SDK that you could mention (and update tags as well..)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the service being used with your network request. For example, when you visit www.google.com you are using the HTTP or https protocol which is through port 80 and 443 respectively. In your example with requesting an image, I believe port 80 and 443 would be the appropriate ports to be open for this task on your server.